# How to sort array of PHAssets by size

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have thousand of `PHAssets` in array(arrayOfAsset), I know how to sort that array by creation date.

`[[arrayOfAsset objectAtIndex:j1 ] sortUsingDescriptors:@[[NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES]]];`

But I don't know how to sort that array by size of asset.

Comment: There is no property for size in `PHAsset` class,  but what you can do is get the actual media NSData from 'PHAsset' and create a different set of array with size calculating from NSData, as `data.length`, then when you get all the size sort them with size key. But this may cause huge memory consumption as you are saying you have lot of images.

Comment: you can sort according to image size.

Comment: @iphonic thanks for your answer. I tried the way what you are saying. For less count of images its working fine but if I go for more than 2500 images its getting crash. Is there any other way???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you can use `pixelWidth` and `pixelHeight` to roughly sort according to the size. Assuming for photos only. For videos you need to include `duration` in the sorting.

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortByWidth = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pixelWidth" ascending:YES];
NSSortDescriptor *sortByHeight = [NSSortDescriptor sortDescriptorWithKey:@"pixelHeight" ascending:YES];
[[arrayOfAsset objectAtIndex:j1] sortUsingDescriptors:@[sortByWidth,sortByHeight]];
```

Comment: can u please explain how to get size of image from asset. pixelWidth & asset. pixelHeight ???

Comment: Thanks for your answer. i tried lot with sample code but it's not working.

Comment: In array, i have 8 phassets of sizes(241KB,245KB,240KB,238KB,241KB,238KB,238KB,235KB). but all assets have same pixelWidth  & pixelHeight. how can we sort by pixelWidth, pixelHeight ??

Comment: Yes. That case, I have no idea. I think there is no way to do that if size is same but bytes are different.